# How to save data retrieved from DatePicker to Database?

Tags: android, datepicker

I am new to android development. I hope you can help me on how to save the data retrieved from dialogfragment to my database. My current code is able to save data but only the current date not the chosen one.

```
public class RemindersFragment extends Fragment  {


    private EditText mTitleText;
    private EditText mBodyText;
    public static final String DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss";
    private Button mConfirmButton;
    private Long mRowId;
    private RemindersDbAdapter mDbHelper;
    private Calendar mCalendar;

    Button btnChangeDate,btnChangeTime;
    TextView txtDisplayDate,txtDisplayTime;


    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;

    private int hour;
    private int minute;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         mDbHelper = new RemindersDbAdapter(getActivity());

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reminders, container, false);
          mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
            mTitleText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            mBodyText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.body);
            mConfirmButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.confirm);
            btnChangeDate = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnChangeDate);
            btnChangeTime = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnChangeTime);
            txtDisplayTime = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtTime);
            txtDisplayDate = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
            mRowId = savedInstanceState != null ? savedInstanceState.getLong(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID) 
                                                : null;

            registerButtonListenersAndSetDefaultText();

            btnChangeDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showDatePickerDialog();
                }
            });

            btnChangeTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showTimePickerDialog();
                }
            });


        return rootView;
    }


    // display current date
        public void showCurrentDateOnView() {

            year = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            month = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            day = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // set current date into textview
            txtDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 based, just add 1
                .append(month + 1).append("-").append(day).append("-")
                .append(year).append(" "));

        }


        // display current time
        public void showCurrentTimeOnView() {

            hour = mCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            minute = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            // set current time into textview
            txtDisplayTime.setText(
                        new StringBuilder().append(hour)
                                           .append(":").append(minute));

        }


    private void setRowIdFromIntent() {
        if (mRowId == null) {
            Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();            
            mRowId = extras != null ? extras.getLong(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID) 
                                    : null;

        }
    }

    public void showDatePickerDialog() {
        DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment(txtDisplayDate);
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

    }

    public void showTimePickerDialog() {
        TimePickerFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment(txtDisplayTime);
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
    }



    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mDbHelper.close(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mDbHelper.open(); 
        setRowIdFromIntent();
        populateFields();
    }


    private void registerButtonListenersAndSetDefaultText() {

        mConfirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent;
                saveState(); 
                getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.task_saved_message), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplication(), Manage_Settings.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });

         showCurrentDateOnView();
            showCurrentTimeOnView();

    }

    private void populateFields()  {



        // Only populate the text boxes and change the calendar date
        // if the row is not null from the database. 
        if (mRowId != null) {
            Cursor reminder = mDbHelper.fetchReminder(mRowId);
            getActivity().startManagingCursor(reminder);
            mTitleText.setText(reminder.getString(
                    reminder.getColumnIndexOrThrow(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE)));
            mBodyText.setText(reminder.getString(
                    reminder.getColumnIndexOrThrow(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_BODY)));


            // Get the date from the database and format it for our use. 
            SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
            Date date = null;
            try {
                String dateString = reminder.getString(reminder.getColumnIndexOrThrow(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_DATE_TIME)); 
                date = dateTimeFormat.parse(dateString);
                mCalendar.setTime(date); 
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                Log.e("ReminderEditActivity", e.getMessage(), e); 
            } 
        } else {
            // This is a new task - add defaults from preferences if set. 
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity()); 
            String defaultTitleKey = getString(R.string.pref_task_title_key); 
            String defaultTimeKey = getString(R.string.pref_default_time_from_now_key); 

            String defaultTitle = prefs.getString(defaultTitleKey, null);
            String defaultTime = prefs.getString(defaultTimeKey, null); 

            if(defaultTitle != null)
                mTitleText.setText(defaultTitle); 

            if(defaultTime != null)
                mCalendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(defaultTime));

        }

         showCurrentDateOnView();
            showCurrentTimeOnView();

    }


    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putLong(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId);
    }



    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    private void saveState() {
        String title = mTitleText.getText().toString();
        String body = mBodyText.getText().toString();
        SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME_FORMAT);        
        String reminderDateTime = dateTimeFormat.format(mCalendar.getTime());

        if (mRowId == null) {

            long id = mDbHelper.createReminder(title, body, reminderDateTime);
            if (id > 0) {
                mRowId = id;
            }
        } else {
            mDbHelper.updateReminder(mRowId, title, body, reminderDateTime);
        }

        new ReminderManager(getActivity()).setReminder(mRowId, mCalendar); 
    }


}
```

And here is for my Datepicker DialogFragment:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

    TextView txtDate;


     public DatePickerFragment(TextView txtDate) {
        super();
        this.txtDate = txtDate;
    }

    @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            //DatePickerFragmentListener listener = (DatePickerFragmentListener) getTargetFragment();

            txtDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
                   .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
                   .append(" "));
        }



}
```

What I've done so far:

I tried to set the mCalendar at the current date but I don't think I'm doing it right:

```
// display current date
    public void showCurrentDateOnView() {

        year = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        mCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
        // set current date into textview
        txtDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder()
            // Month is 0 based, just add 1
            .append(month + 1).append("-").append(day).append("-")
            .append(year).append(" "));

    }
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I have done it in one of my apps was:
1) Just as you, I have a TextField to store the date. So I have created setOnFocusChangeListener & setOnClickListener which will create a DatePickerDialog where we can scroll to set our date.

```
txtDOB.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus){
            CallenderCall();
        }
    }
});

txtDOB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        CallenderCall();        
    }
});
```

As you can see, inside of them I am calling CallenderCall(); which is:

```
public void CallenderCall(){
    //Creates new instance of calendar, get current Year, Month and Day and use it as default values for the Date Picker Dialog.
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    todayYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    todayMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    todayDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog dpdFromDate = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), mDateSetListener, todayYear, todayMonth, todayDay);
    dpdFromDate.show();
}
```

This CallenderCall as we can see creates DatePickerDialog so there is another function requiered to make it all work:

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    // onDateSet method
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {


        if (year > todayYear || year >= todayYear &&  monthOfYear > todayMonth || year >= todayYear &&  monthOfYear >= todayMonth && dayOfMonth > todayDay) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Date of Birth can't be from the future ;)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            txtDOB.setText("");
        }else{
            dateOfBirth = String.valueOf(dayOfMonth) + "/" + String.valueOf(monthOfYear+1) + "/" + String.valueOf(year);
            txtDOB.setText(dateOfBirth);
            Log.v("MAD","Date: "+dateOfBirth);   
        }



    } 
}; // DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener close
```

Now, you will have the date in the textbox as a string, which you can save in database. I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should override the method onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) from DatePickerDialog in your class DatePickerFragment.

and put your code

```
   txtDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder()
        // Month is 0 based, just add 1
        .append(month + 1).append("-").append(day).append("-")
        .append(year).append(" "));
```

into that method.

**My current code is able to save data but only the current date not the chosen one.**

so, I think maybe your problem is that you can't get the chosen date.

And I advise that you override the method form the subclass DatePickerDialog
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html

DatePickerDialog has already implemented OnDateChangedListener,so it can handle date change stuff. And you just use it.

you defined a method onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day)  in your DatePickerFragment , I'm afraid it not work.

hope I said it clearly

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you please expound your answer? I am not quite familiar with android development.